# LESS in IE throws exceptions

Tags: javascript, less

I am playing aorund with using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) along with [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to streamline the development of a new site.  Both LESS and respond are quite simply neat.  However, with LESS in IE I have run into many problems.

For starters in IE8 mode my IE10 reported that id did not understand "map".  No problems, I wrote up an Array.prototype map extension.  Then it said that it did not understand isArray, once again in IE8 mode.  Prototype extensions to the rescue again.  Now it comes back saying something along the lines of SyntaxError: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

I am not in fact aware of what **in** might be but in any case I cannot keep adding adhoc prototype extenions on the fly in the hope that things will eventually settle down.  Either LESS is unusable with IE or else someone here can point me to all the fixes needed to make it work.

Comment: Just to make sure... Are you embedding the less file in your html or the compiled css file?

Comment: There is actually an injunction on the LESS website that it works client side only on "modern browsers".  They do not specify how they define "modern" but I guess it means IE9+.  In any case I abandoned off-the-shelf CSS preprocessors in favor of a lightweight homespun PHP script that does the job just as well.  You did guess right though - my issues were arising because I was embedding the LESS in the HTML and that drove IE9- into a tizzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for your question:

First of all, LESS client side compilation is supported only in IE9+. 
You could probably fix this using shims and polyfills for ES5, like [these](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills).

But please, don't.

### What you should probably do (and forget the first part):

However, despite of really good caching mechanisms provided by the LESS compiler (eg. using localStorage to preserve generated code) using it i production isn't considered a good practice.

[GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Bower.io](http://bower.io/) work in the console, but are relatively easy to configure. Basically, you set them up once and forget they've ever existed:)

[Livereload](http://livereload.com/) provides you with a GUI and it's **incredibly easy to use**.

I used GruntJS for frontend development with backend developers working with PHP (CakePHP, Zend, Laravel) and it made our lives much, much easier :)

**It seems much more reasonable to streamline your frontend development workflow using a task runner like GruntJS or Brunch.io or install Livereload. These tools will monitor the file changes and generate a new CSS file on every save (and also, reload your CSS on the fly).**

You can install GrunJS with [watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and [LESS](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) plugins and keep is very simple this way. You could even use [LESS Node.js](https://npmjs.org/package/less) package installed globally to the job.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  As I mentioned in my comment in response to @ToniTornado I eventually abandoned LESS in favor of a PHP script to dynmaically generate my stylesheets.  However, it is always nice to get pointers to other tools, APIs etc - bound to come in handy sooner or later.

Comment: Yeah, sure, glad to help even a little bit then. I just thought it might be a better solution for this particular problem. I've spent a lot of time trying to find the most efficient and painless way to do front-end development and decouple my projects from back-end (mostly php) devs, and the method I've mentioned seems to solve the issue here. Just saying :)

On a side note, I'd try to avoid using PHP with LESS or any javascript-based technologies (even if it's a port). Based on my experience I can say that usually, node packages have a much better support and test coverage.